# Runtime responsible for killing an Android application

Tags: android, runtime, android-lifecycle

When Android kills an application due to a shortage of resources system-wide, is it the Android runtime (meaning, the virtual machine) that does the killing, or the Linux runtime?

I've come across descriptions where "the runtime" kills an application.  But I'm often left without a clear sense of which runtime exactly.

I don't think it could be the Android runtime doing the killing, because the Android runtime runs within the process being killed.  Unless by "killing", one means killing the application, not destroying the process within which it runs. But if that's the case, how does the runtime interact with the Linux kernel, whose processes are ultimately what are started and stopped whenever that needs to happen, for whatever reason?

I need some clarity... clearly :)

Comment: What is "the Linux runtime"?

Comment: what kind of problem do you want to solve?

Comment: @CommonsWare Ok, maybe part of my lack of clarity.  By Linux runtime I meant the Linux environment containing every process and every instance of the Android runtime.  The layer between the Android runtime and the physical device.  In my attempt at specificity, maybe I introduced a term that doesn't exist.

Comment: @gio :) My problem is ignorance.  I wish to solve it.

Comment: What you are seeking is a bit broader than what Stack Overflow is well-suited for, IMHO. You may wish to pick up [a book on Android internals](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920021094.do). In the end, everything is a Linux process: apps, core OS, etc. Android decides what apps need to be terminated to free up system RAM, and Android (usually) triggers appropriate `onDestroy()` calls via IPC. Linux, however, is what actually terminates the process.

Comment: @CommonsWare Ok. Thanks for the book recommendation.  I'll read it.  So should I close the question?

Comment: You are welcome to leave it open if you want. I am just warning you that you may not get a response.

Comment: @CommonsWare  [This from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Runtime) suggests that there is a concept of a "device runtime" separate from the Android runtime  - "Android Runtime (ART) is an application runtime environment used by the Android operating system. ART replaces Dalvik, which is the process virtual machine originally used by Android, and performs transformation of the application's bytecode into native instructions that are later executed by the **device's runtime environment**"

Comment: IMHO, you are misinterpreting that sentence. In that sentence, the "device's runtime environment" is ART.

Comment: @CommonsWare Assuming you're right, the wikipedia author is muddying the water unnecessarily by referring to the same entity two different ways.

Comment: Agreed. Frankly, that quoted passage sucks on a variety of levels. I'd fix it now, but I am rather short on sleep. :-)